# CakePHP join table

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a join model UserCommission which joins User model and Commission model.
User model belongs to Organisation model. And Organisation model has many User model.

In my model UserCommission, with `$this->find('all')` I get this array :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'UserCommission' => array(
            'id' => '1247',
            'user_id' => '872',
            'commission_id' => '13'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '872',
            'organisation_id' => '6', // I need data related to Organisation model
        ),
        'Commission' => array(
            'id' => '13',
            'nom' => 'SALARIES CE'
        )
    ),
    ...
)
```

How can I get data from Organisation model so that the returned array is like so :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'UserCommission' => array(
            'id' => '1247',
            'user_id' => '872',
            'commission_id' => '13'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '872',
            'organisation_id' => '6',
        ),
        'Commission' => array(
            'id' => '13',
            'nom' => 'SALARIES CE'
        ),
        'Organisation' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'nom' => 'The Organisation #6'
        )
    ),
    ...
)
```

**Model associations :**
User belongsTo Organisation
Organisation hasMany User
User hasAndBelongsToMany Commission (with UserCommission)
Commission hasAndBelongsToMany User  (with UserCommission)
UserCommission belongsTo User
UserCommission belongsTo Commission

**Model tables :**
User (id; organisation_id; username; ...)
Commission (id; commission_name; ...)
Organisation (id; organisation_name; ...)
UserCommission (id; user_id; commission_id; ...)

Comment: Try this $this->User->Organisation->find('all');

Comment: It doesn't help me. I believe I have to use the *JOINS* option to join UserCommission, User, and Organisation, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: You _generally_ don't need to use JOINs as long as your model relations are properly defined. Share the **User** model's **$hasAndBelongsToMany**, **$hasMany** and **$belongsTo** configurations in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If relations are properly configured you can use:

```
$User->recursive=2;
$User->find('all')
```

The problem with this workaround is that you will get Organization info nested within user array, not at the same level and that is really bad resources wise. It really depends on how many organizations are in your database but sometimes is better to just make a second query to retrieve needed info instead of make huge queries just to have it on one go.

Comment: Yes, this is working, but as you say, I am getting a huge amount of data. Too much. To avoid it, I am going to make a second query. Thank you for your help.